# Typescript - Is it possible to reference interfaces from extended interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typemaps

I wanted to add chained functionality to all of the interfaces in HTMLElementTagNameMap.
Since there are dozens of them and all of the elements either are `HTMLElement` or extend it, I thought there should be a way of doing something like this:

```
interface HTMLElement {
    doSomething<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(anArgument: any): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]
}
```

This of course doesn't work, because every interface extending `HTMLElement` now contains a `doSomething` method that is expected to return any of the `HTMLElementTagNameMap` values. Instead, I want for `HTMLTableElement.doSomething` to return an object of type `HTMLTableElement`, `HTMLDivElement.doSomething` to return an object of type `HTMLDivElement` and so on.

Is such a generalization possible or do I need to 'duplicate' it for every interface?

And if it is possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a return type of [`this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) is what you want.

[Here's a demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIBUCyAZAogGwgFsJxkBvAWAChk7kYB7RgCgEoAuZMAC2AGcA3DQC+NGgkYh+YZHGQBeZABNGCAK4lwAOgRQIcSAWKkwLAERxzbYdUnTZcAEZOoilWs2nd+wxGNaZpYuUNa29jJyysr6-PzuqhqBPgZGhIEWcNGx-GESUpFwvgmeyXqp-ummmb55dgWOUGDACIQlSd7lfgHVlk0thHURjvzAyihKiV46XWkm4Jmj40MNcurKwIzt02Ap3VULluubKw7ITttlvnMZ5k6nkU5w-BMeHTPXlfNBTy8Psk4NpdOp8eodAcB-udVMCPhUwT9VFCnPg1ABrACO6kYkFhu1mX1uKPRWJxEGRjGUAE88Xsbr0nJSqci3JNSiD4QcfqEbPkzk51GAwFJaQSERYBUKpFCEHAQAA3Z6i0FciyyhXPGVwAAOzRFbPe+JV3zVOr1IBlwFxBp2dMJvQQVvJvPqZ0k42VnJN5ndzvCq0k+E9+29gZljHwAHMoIx1Nrg-TDoHo7HtVDlIZ5Darl7bhmwFYXcMVJn8AJZNmOSG86Xy+nlAn7YdoumIEHK3Dq71xvhWwXgPh4h2jbnuxB+4P0zAQI3xeZlNP08A4KjI7PVfPl6ul6y3raxRuNjz-WcNvL196z+n23uc13m72i6tlBXb1XE0EX1DiBfbsRv0QTgQA2w52nOxBAcoUIwMAbbKC8r5THeH4WDBcEIdBwCRrKuqbDOoEHt6MHYWaeGYZG6j6L+vTEZRfp8pETBkARxq3ExYDQcwkC7kh75NkETBkseDGyEwUBENRhxiUQ0FQHAJCSQJckkLJ8kQAhimocp6njlCPAAIyaeYBl6QATEZPCmXpADMFnWXpAAsFkOXpACsFmuXpABsFleXpBggW+nYocZAX+Vk0AWQF0B6SmcYWXFaZPmcPA8eywX8RYqV6WARA3rxGVzjwuWPiekTAEZkLJeVMDaZVtVqVCwBEGuLGjoczWRk1IDaoKlU9YK3VDkFI73kEoC5NVshooCRkzVBU3IPgzhtkZy1AaVIlLRAkakIFBWjSFhC7SAC1lbIZZrVV51LaAaJXSAaJQkQcCgEZL2gM9OrvTqX1QPdbVjRYL3-X9WIQK8B1gRuIPg-RrqRFo6jvaQ6jPeOWYjdD3okAW6PcSj3FQiAcDnoDIUk-KxOMPwejALqRkgDTdO6lCjBOAAVhACCIelh2ZeY7NczzbP5Xz2O3BGbO6olRmMDLMZxtL5py7h0qLbGYC9bzhoS70mva1C8bkwLSU3dqRTyUZFvKUbLRgHR1v23RRtUSbc7avoruMNG6nDVDhG3J7Ps5FCGJGRiUJQMbWOB700dRzr+6sfHHGLVA6hODS7sbhnWdQv74tx4ck03fw8kxwHKclxXBcs0nyEC7TUD02nZfcyrOfei8PNkYtLyEDzRkDx3Beog3fFzvw48Fy9+Bi7rxdBPwc+bQjsj8LGUBIMPW9IAXFv4bH1fL4fBdgDGICtcf7XLxfUhdf3YBUm0Xe3DIL-w8W-CZ8PmcF5oEG2cb5A3MD-IgQCAGVyLifCwP8zZbQLCiSGMDb4WCQYMRaYBGTUiMtgpkUIwD7VQaAohhDiDamWtaEBIVIBEEoX4chAAPAsxQ369EgCwooBhCGCQnoVDcYA+GEJ4HgngIiApiLClg5qKDF6wPMM0FSMiwCvxoQLZoqiv6rAvng4S69uByQQADdRc4L6ICeotZG7DDhoysQvZOaDzDqDXsWRUUACBGXcVCeUYwIBbBsUEXx4xGBQgAO6uCMhE-RW04AADFmDuDgNoQS7AbrOFcAkgJcgQgpOYGk2J2Q-ZZKSUUuIeTWCLW4fExJShqkVIKQYoozRWgQBKXU-orSGlVKWG02pchendPSccRg7S1gbEYEMraTgxlOCmQY34fTsmLPmcWCEsyNirNWICUZ-SdlbP5KiYxpJICzKOZibEkADmPCZLMpk1yARQFmVAB55xBTChALM95UhXnqkVPwMZfzni-NIlIQFoKQC-KdICp0vzKRLPcL6OF+BAURmRYlVFUZFbalefmGp2S8W4trDIMZeKywyFxcoUlyhcVtlJW2WlE4AX9PGEy3F05SXTlxVuH2pKeWRm5U8llwAXmpMWmePl8pcUopZfgXFYBSW7DFTdYgYziCvIgsBNVgFgKvLQvgeC44xn6sNUq-Ji1iI4XNMarCVq8J6qwnRG1FF9B6qkAq-p7E3VCWNVxaAbrxK+vEnq7SxrtIhrUghMNkbxyvIMmMgycbTIJtMnG6yCbrJxocgmhycbXIJtcnGryCavJxoCgmgKZaIpCuyTwaKorzU3R4Bi-pzbsVxpre4VKcaSoJpKq84AYzgADoaiQIdo6IADpakOlqA6BoeuyaAbWc7mWLukK8+aYz5qvPWnS-pu65XKq2sdPaYyT2nR3YO-dw6j0GLLI9M9d1XkfU+f0l9z6dRjJeji29xYQZoi-UUNEH6oBw0A6B9QENn2oy-ajaDBZYMFng9ARD-rf2rEpmMymrymbN1blh5mLddSvKFh3MZpGeYkZldktF6GzjyzAC2mjCtUwkbVq+5j5oSOCm1uRnjgpXnajGT+xtW0bbyWE5bIggnnb6GE7JyddHIiewRUoFTgmYy+ziMJzTORXkYjGRiV50cxnR2Mwu9wTRjOZypKZmzrzV3uH4A5iuYzy70Ic-XNz9cHMdzwm5vzPylMbzbGR-pI9KPBeQNPHEbnx4OdXm51eDm96qei6lhzh83OHwc-fK+bm8sCqix-QgBXP4Oczm5zOFWIFFFs+FwBdWKtCYayJypN0MFpc668-B1Ixm9apD1ql-SiE9YoVQrr42-Bja4b4frEBZsGB63w-rfCes8H6zwdb5aRt1qyD12R-XZEHa0UdrRPXO1KAvhdix-WjHAai+oMZ6hXkuOe4e0TBj3FjPcQQV5wT-E-b8ZMqL0SxnRPmUAA):

```
interface HTMLElement {
    foo(): this;
}

const a = document.createElement("a");

// ...

const aFoo = a.foo();
//    ^^^^
// HTMLAnchorElement

// ...
```

In the demo, you can hover over the variable that has the result of calling `foo` assigned to it and see the type is the interface for the respective HTML element.